# grails is missing create-job command

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 4.0.3.  I follow the Quartz instruction but Grails says there is no such create-job command. Would you point me to correct instruction please?

Thanks!

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a dependency on the plugin in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13'
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is strange.  I already had added the plugin yesterday.  I wasn't able to run create-job.  It kept saying it could not compile create-job.groovy.  It was missing the transaction classes.  Maybe there was a curse  on Sunday.  You never know.  It is working on Monday.